# Store and use static metadata in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I am trying to create Grafana dashboard for a large system. There are thousands of metadata variables which I need to store and access. E.g. SLA's for hundreds of applications. What is the best way to achieve this? My data source for logs and metrics is elastic search.

Should I store the static data as Elastic search index and query along with main data or is it possible to store it in some other DB and access it with main elastic search data.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Best is to handle all metadata before and only feed Grafana with indexes ready for display.

The only source of data in Grafana is the 'data source'. There is no way to get any sort of metadata in Grafana. Especially with ElasticSearch(ES) as a data source which is fairly new to Grafana.

The best way to configure any metadata is in an ES index or to model your data along with the metadata using a transformation or ingestion in ES. As suggested in  tl;dr it is best to handle all the correlation and transformation beforehand and let Grafana just query indices to render graphs.

However, if you need any aggregations to be performed on the data Grafana does support it. You can check it in the [official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/elasticsearch/)